# Java regex substring from certain charater to another character

Tags: java, regex, substring

i'm new here and this is my first question. I researched this topic as best as I could and almost found my solution. I have examples of strings that look like this:

```
String product = "1 x Winter gloves \"Husky\" - wool(60 dollars)"
```

I am trying to extract only the product name: `Winter gloves "Husky" - wool`
I know there are two possible solutions, either with .replaceAll method or with Pattern Matcher.

I tried this:

```
System.out.println(product.replaceAll(".*x ([^;]*)", "$1"));
```

output is this :

```
Winter gloves "Husky" - wool(60 dollars)
```

I just need to finalize the formula so that the string will "stop" at the first "(" symbol it encounters. This way I will get my desired result: Winter gloves "Husky" - wool

Any help is appreciated.
Thanky you.

Comment: System.out.println(product.replaceAll(".*x ([^;]*)(\\(.*)", "$1")); There is double \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first match the digit(s) , then  `x`  and capture in group 1 matching any char except `(` instead of `;`

```
^\d+ x ([^(]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t8yEJm/1)

If you want to use replace, you can match the opening till closing parenthesis after it and replace with group 1:

```
^\d+ x ([^(]*)\([^()]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bfSVlz/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/DJOPQ0)

```
String product = "1 x Winter gloves \"Husky\" - wool(60 dollars)";
System.out.println(product.replaceAll("^\\d+ x ([^(]*)\\([^()]+\\)", "$1"));
```

Output

```
Winter gloves "Husky" - wool
```